# avoid Excel implicit intersection operator when using openxlsx in R

Tags: r, excel, intersection, implicit, openxlsx

I am using the openxlsx package in R to make an Excel worksheet which will later have data added to it one row per day.

I am having problems with formulae where I am using ISERROR and STDEV.P, but not with just AVERAGE, MIN, or MAX.  Excel is adding an implicit intersection operator (@) to my formulae.  I removed my ISERROR code, but I am still having the problem woth STDEV.P

After creating the workbook, wb, and putting headers into it, my code simplified is:

```
formula1 <- "AVERAGE(E2:E32)"
formula2 <- "AVERAGE(IF(ISERROR(E2:E32),"",E2:E32))"
formula3 <- "STDEV.P(IF(ISERROR(E2:E32),"",E2:E32))"
formula4 <- "STDEV.P(E2:E34)"
writeFormula(wb, 1, x=formula1, startCol = 5, startRow = 34)
writeFormula(wb, 1, x=formula2, startCol = 5, startRow = 35)
writeFormula(wb, 1, x=formula3, startCol = 5, startRow = 36)
writeFormula(wb, 1, x=formula4, startCol = 5, startRow = 37)
writeFormula(wb, 1, x=formula5, startCol = 5, startRow = 38)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "Log.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

This is what Excel does to my formula:

```
formula1
What in R is the string:  AVERAGE(E2:E32)
What Excel shows:        =AVERAGE(E2:E32)             ok; works

formula2
What in R is the string:  AVERAGE(IF(ISERROR(E2:E32),"",E2:E32))
What Excel shows:        =AVERAGE(IF(ISERROR(@E2:E32),"",E2:E32))    value error in Excel

formula3
What in R is the string:  STDEV.P(IF(ISERROR(E2:E32),"",E2:E32))
What Excel shows:        =@STDEV.P(IF(ISERROR(@E2:E32),"",E2:E32))   name error in Excel

formula4
What in R is the string:  STDEV.P(E2:E34)
What Excel shows:        =@STDEV.P(E2:E34)               Name error in Excel
```

Each formula with the @ added does NOT work in Excel, whether or not I have data in E2:E34.  I am getting a ?NAME error for formulae using STDEV.P and value errors for other ones.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Is there something I can add to my R code to force Excel to stop adding these @?
Is there some way to change my formula strings in R so that Excel will not give an error?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Likely a Office 365 specific issue, since I can't replicate the appearance of the @ symbol in Office 2019.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, xilliam.  Because I tried your formulae I've discovered that Excel computes the stdev a little wonky when there are errors involved.  It's acting as if there is an extra data value equal to 0 in my column, making my stdev be a little off.   (I'm actually getting the sample std dev, despite the stdev.p) Since new data will be input into the file  only through RR(after R pulls chat logs from our data base) I won't need the formulae to adjust their values within Excel itself, so I'm just going to run all the formulae in R and send the results to the Excel file.

Comment: Ah good, I'm glad you found a way forward.

Answer (score 2):

I can't replicate the Excel error to show `@` in the Excel formula but the reason why you get the `#VALUE` with the formula `AVERAGE(IF(ISERROR(E2:E32),"",E2:E32))` is because `ISERROR` requires a cell input rather than the range.
So if you change this to `AVERAGE(IF(ISERROR(E2),"",E2:E32))` then this should work.

Also make sure to replace the double quotes `"` in the beginning and at the end with a single `'`.  This is required because in your Excel formula you are using `"` and R would think this is the end of the string `"`.

If you are using an Excel function that includes `.` then your formula should begin with `_xlfn.`  so to use `STDEV.P` this should be `_xlfn.STDEV.P(E2:E34)`.

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "1")

# This works
formula1 <- "AVERAGE(E2:E32)"

# This won't work (note it begins with a single ')
formula2 <- 'AVERAGE(IF(ISERROR(E2:E32),"",E2:E32))'

# This should work
formula3 <- 'AVERAGE(IF(ISERROR(E2),"",E2:E32))'

# This won't work
formula4 <- 'STDEV.P(IF(ISERROR(E2:E32),"",E2:E32))'
formula5 <- "STDEV.P(E2:E34)"

# This should work. For a Excel functions with . start with _xlfn
formula6 <- "_xlfn.STDEV.P(E2:E34)"
    
writeData(wb, 1, 1:30, startRow = 2, startCol = 5)
writeFormula(wb, 1, x=formula1, startCol = 5, startRow = 34)
writeFormula(wb, 1, x=formula2, startCol = 5, startRow = 35)
writeFormula(wb, 1, x=formula3, startCol = 5, startRow = 36)
writeFormula(wb, 1, x=formula4, startCol = 5, startRow = 37)
writeFormula(wb, 1, x=formula5, startCol = 5, startRow = 38)
writeFormula(wb, 1, x=formula6, startCol = 5, startRow = 39)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "Log.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the `_xlfn.` bit. It was a bit help for me! +1

Comment: I hadn't seen this answer around the time I first wrote my question, but the issue just came up again, and this time I need the actual formula to be in Excel, rather than the value, so I checked back here and that "_xlfn." did the trick.  Thank you so much!  I'm adding this to my list of openxlsx cautions list.